# Trying to insert in-line HTML to iframe srcdoc tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array filled with the HTML contents I want, as well as a way to map each of the contents to the proper iframe.

Here is the chunk of code I am using

```
function replaceFrames(docElement) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(docElement.querySelectorAll("iframe, frame"), function (node) {

        var name = node.getAttribute("name");

        var blah = singlefile.test[name];

        node.setAttribute("srcdoc",blah);
    });
}
```

The docElement parameter is a  [standard DOM Element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

I would use JQUERY, but I feel like I wont be able to modify what I want, since I dont have access to the Document, just the specific element/node.

The problem is, in my output document I have "&gt'; and &lt'; instead of the tags (ignore the quotes there, it was just to make it pop up.)

Comment: Please do not use w3schools as your sole source for information

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I was merely providing a sample source for the DOM api

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks http://w3fools.com